# How to Connect PWA to my Magento 1 site. magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, pwa

Since I'm a newbie in **Magento1** and also in **PWA(Progressive Web App)** so maybe my question is not that much good... but I just learned last night that we can connect **Magento1** and also **Magento2** sites to PWA for speedup.. Now I want to know that how can I connect my Magento1 site to PWA??

Comment: Magento 1 does not  Support PWA  by default. Magento 2.3 is support PWA.

Comment: So @AmitBera Sir we cannot connect M1 sites with PWA or there is any alternative way for this?

Comment: I searched this https://divante.co/blog/pwa-magento-1-9-can/  n after that I came to now that we can connect to PWA M1 or M2 site

Comment: You already give your answer. Magento1.9 does have  PWA default but 3party   system has  PWA for  Magento 1.9.

Comment: n for M 2.3.X they support PWA?? like we don't need 3rd party for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Vue Storefront](https://www.vuestorefront.io/) from Divante and [Vue Storefront integration for Magento 1](https://github.com/DivanteLtd/magento1-vsbridge)

Comment: Actually I have an issue to how can I use this to connect... I already searched both of these sites. Like I can get the code form https://github.com/DivanteLtd/magento1-vsbridge but where to use this code in **M1**